# Resolve DNS lookup to local IP on consumer hardware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ip

I will be presenting an demo of an webapp i have been working on and I need to redirect a DNS lookup `eg. example.local` to an local IP address.

There will be no internet access when i am presenting and users will be using their own devices. This is a remote location and I will be carrying my laptop (on which the webapp server service runs) and a router to establish a local wireless network (without internet access).

Users will be connecting to the network and they will type in the link in their browser. I want link to resolve to the IP address of my laptop (which will also be connected to network) on which the webapp is being served.

My corrent solution is to set the DNS server on my router to my laptop's IP and then running a DNS server on it which will resolve DNS lookups to the IP of the same laptop. Is there a better solution to this? There will be 30-50 users connecting simultaneously.

P.S. I am using Linux on my laptop. I can also carry an rapsberry Pi if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If it would be me, I will setup [pFsense](https://pfsense.org/) in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) instead of hardware router. You would have then ability to override DNS (map to a local IP) in DNS forwarder service (well, not only local resource, you can substitute your own google to a local IP)

To be able to share your laptop resources, you can use WiFi router in AP (access point) mode that will match local network set in Pfsence

Comment: This would work. I ready have Virtualbox installed and x86 image of pfSense (used for my home network). Will do this first thing tomorrow morning.